# Can I use this in AngularJS {{ array [ {{index }} ] }}?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Basically I have a list like this :

```
Apples - 1
Oranges - 2
Pears - 0
```

I want to turn the quantity of fruits in something like this, when it is 0 it should print none, a few when it is 1 and a lot when it is 2.

```
Apples - a few
Oranges - a lot
Pears - none
```

So I've created on array

```
$scope.quantityToString = ["none", "a few", "a lot"];
```

And try to render this in HTML

```
{{ quantityToString [ {{ quantity }} ] }}
```

But it is not working.

Is there any way how to get it work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `{{ }}` inside `[]`. Think of `quantityToString[quantity]` expression as normal javascript code. So it should be:

```
{{ quantityToString[quantity] }}
```